# Class does not append on javascript appendChild() function

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an `onclick()` event on a button, to execute te following code:

```
function digital_tour(){
    let loader = document.createElement("div");
    loader.className = "loader";
    console.log(loader);
    document.getElementById("main-div").appendChild(loader);
}
```

The code works, and the element loader is shown by the console.log and returns:

```
<div class="loader"></div>
```

The loader div get appended into the main-div, including the class, but my css style is not shown. My CSS code

```
.main-bg .loader{
    width: 100vw;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: green;
    z-index: 5;
}
```

I want to show the CSS style to the loader div, but it does not work. What do I need to do to make this work?

Comment: The class says  its parent `main-bg` but you are appending it as a child to `main-div`

Comment: Does element by id `main-div` have class `main-bg` set? If not you could try selector `#main-div .loader` instead.

Comment: Have you tried to append content into `<div class="loader">`. The code that you show here will just be an element with zero height.

Comment: you should add the html code to your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the CSS class works like this: `.main-bg .loader` means you should have an element with main-bg class which has an element with the .loader class inside in other words the CSS you have will only be applied to a loader class which is inside the element with main-bg class. but you are appending loader to main-div not main-bg.